# EF Core - conditional relationship - vertical table splitting

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I've to deal with a special relationship, due to an existing database schema.
The db:
- table Cat (id, name)
- table Dog (id, name)
- view Animals:

```
SELECT 'C' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR) AS AnimalId, Id AS OriginalId, Name, 1 AS AnimalType 
FROM Cat
UNION
SELECT 'D' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR) AS AnimalId, Id AS OriginalId, Name, 2 AS AnimalType 
FROM Dog
```

- table Consult (AnimalId, Date)

Now I need to navigate to a Cat, from my Consult-entity.
I've define four entities:

1. Cat
2. Dog
3. Animal
4. Consult

The relation Consult-Animal is no problem.
But I need to get the Cat when AnimalType = 2.

What I'm trying to do is something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Cat>()
    .HasOne(a => a.Animal)
    .WithOne(a => a.Cat)
    .HasForeignKey<Cat>(k => k.Id)
    .HasPrincipalKey<Animal>(pk => pk.OriginalId && pk.AnimalType == 1);
```

The SQL-join should be something like this:

```
SELECT Animal.*, Cat.*
FROM Animal LEFT JOIN 
    Cat ON (Animal.OriginalId = Cat.Id AND Animal.AnimalType = 1)
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Please show the classes code. It not clear if `Cat` and `Dog` inherit from `Animal`.

Comment: This looks like Table-Per-Type inheritence, which EF Core doesn't support https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2266  You can possibly use the UNION ALL view in conjunction with CRUD stored procedures or INSTEAD OF triggers.

Comment: @GertArnold they don't inherit.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Animal is only needed for read/navigate, but is doesn't have all the necessary properties (and deeper navigation)

Comment: That still sounds like Table-per-Type inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the join like this

```
from a in context.Animal
join c in context.Cat
on new {a.OriginalId, a.AnimalType} equals {c.Id, 1}
select new {a, c}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking for a way to define it in the context instead in each use.